# events not triggered when on mouseover elements

Tags: javascript, css

I am trying to when i mouse over on Following i need show the Below Pop Over after i am trying to click on events but is it not triggered, can any one help me about this please? !

```
+---------+
|  click  |  <span>Click</span>
+---------+

+----------+
| Click 1  |  <div><a>Click </a><a> click2</a></div>
| Click 2  |
+----------+
```

When i mouse over on **Span element(Click)**

I need show below div, After showing i am trying click the **Click1 and Click2**, But it is not working please any help me about this

Thanks in Advance

Comment: `"events not triggered"` what have you tried for this conclusion?

Comment: Show us what have you tried.

Comment: Please, at least the js if not a fiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the div a child element of the span http://jsfiddle.net/7aa3L9fy/

```
<span>Click
| Click 1  |  <div><a>Click </a><a> click2</a></div>
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

If i got your problem, below is a sample code you can try

```
<span onmouseover="document.getElementById('div').style.display='block'">Click</span>

<div id="div" style="display:none;"><a onclick="alert('click1 is clicked');">Click1 </a><a onclick="alert('click2 is clicked');"> click2</a></div>
```

Please provide some more information if this doesnt solve your problem